# How to setup network proxy in KDE desktop system?

Tags: console, kde-plasma

I want to setup network proxy in `KDE` desktop system. I have found how to setup it in `gnome` desktop system:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'manual'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host '127.0.0.1'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 1080
```

But this not works in `KDE`. I always tried the following but not works.

```
kwriteconfig --file kioslaverc --group 'Proxy Settings' --key ProxyType "1"
kwriteconfig --file kioslaverc --group 'Proxy Settings' --key httpProxy "http://127.0.0.1:1080"
kwriteconfig --file kioslaverc --group 'Proxy Settings' --key Authmode 0
# When you modify kioslaverc, you need to tell KIO.
dbus-send --type=signal /KIO/Scheduler org.kde.KIO.Scheduler.reparseSlaveConfiguration string:''
```

These commands are referred to https://github.com/j1ml/proxydriver/blob/master/proxydriver.sh

Answer (score 1):

I have learned that you need to use `kwriteconfig5` because `kwriteconfig` is the `kdelibs4` version and returns the KDE 4 configuration paths.

Hope it helps.